# Position Text over Video - Flutter-web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm trying to position some text over a video.

The video is currently taking as much space as possible while retaining it's original aspect ratio. Ideally I'd like it to keep doing this as I want the video to resize to fit the browser window.

I'm assuming I need to get get the height/width of the video dynamically..

If anyone knows how to make a video play automatically that would be great as well - I'm using the video_player package.

[image]

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      drawer: ResponsiveLayout.isSmallScreen(context) ? NavDrawer() : null,
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              NavBar(),
              Body(),
              Footer(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveLayout(
      largeScreen: LargeScreen(),
      mediumScreen: LargeScreen(),
      smallScreen: LargeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class LargeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LargeScreenState createState() => _LargeScreenState();
}

class _LargeScreenState extends State<LargeScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.asset(
      'assets/videos/video.mp4',
    );
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _videoPlayerController.initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
                // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the VideoPlayer.
                return AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                  // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                  child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
                );
              } else {
                // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
                // loading spinner.
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: i update my answer to answer all three issues hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap your Widgets in  stack widget and use positioning to position your text

```
 AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                  // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                  child: Stack(children:<Widget>[
                  VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
                   Positioned(bottom:10,left:10,
               child:Text("my text here))
               ])
            )
```

**update**

> If anyone knows how to make a video play automatically that would be great as well - I'm using the video_player package.
>   you can set the state of your video using your controller

```
_videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying
```

> I want the video to resize to fit the browser window.

you can wrap your video in a `SizedBox.expand`  which Creates a box that will become as large as its parent allows.
[sized box constructors](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.expand.html)